# "someone or I" and "me or someone"

Tags: pronouns, objects

I have looked at all the related posts but can't find a definite answer for the following question, so try not to dismiss this as answered:

"John or I will get back to you later"
"Me or John will get back to you later"
"John or me will get back to you later"

Which is correct?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I" is used when it is the subject of the sentence; "me" is used for the object.

So, "John or I will get back to you." But, "You should reply to John or me."

Also, it is considered polite that when giving a list of people that includes yourself to put yourself last. That is, you say "John or I will get back to you" rather than "I or John ...".

As this is one of the few words in English that changes depending on its role in the sentence, English speakers often do not use the correct forms, especially in casual conversation.

Comment: It's only polite most of the time. It might be more polite to put *"I"* first in: *In this case, it's I and John who should take the blame*.

Answer (score 0):

The formal response is "John or I will get back to you later" but in informal or spoken dialogue, the "I" can often get replaced by "me".

Comment: Yes, I think this is what confused me ;)